# Combine value of a task list into hyperlink

Tags: calculated-column, hyperlink, calculated-column-formula

in sharepoint 2007 I want to combine the number - value (of a task in another system) in to an hyperlink like this: "http://172.xxx/Iso/index.php?actie=cs&pt=ontwerp&volgnummer=" and "value of my number - field".
The first value is always the same...

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the build dynamic string operation. This will allow you to create a dynamic string when the workflow is run. You supply any static text you want and can merge it with list item properties using the Add Lookup button. The result is stored in a variable that you can use in other parts of your workflow, like in an email body.